# SQL Server 2005 - Convert varchar Apr 12 2010 12:00AM to varchar 20100412

Tags: date, sql-server-2005, varchar

Can someone please help me update the values in a `varchar` column from `Apr 12 2010 12:00AM` to `20100412`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select CONVERT(varchar,cast('Apr 12 2010 12:00AM' as datetime),112)
```

Comment: That works for the text but when I try to run it against my varchar table I get

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Apr  5 2010 12:00AM' to data type int.

Comment: what does your statement look like ??

Comment: Use adaptv3SAMPLE
select CONVERT(varchar,cast(Value as datetime),112)
from fldval

Comment: There's something else going on that we're not being told, because this statement doesn't try to convert anything to an int, and there's no way I can conceive of that this statement - as is - should cause this error message.

Comment: I'm really not sure why it wouldn't work.

I found that this table was being updated from a datetime table in another database. I ended up running the conversion before the update it is now populating correctly.

Comment: thanks @AaronBertrand for clearing it up/confirming.  I didn't see anything wrong either.